# Can I dynamically create a google form to e-mail based on a template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a form for trainers to report attendance on particular classes to send a standardized report back to HR.  I want to use a spreadsheet to populate the question.  Would I be able to take an existing form and modify the controls on it, or do I need to create the forms entirely in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an add-on for Forms, formRanger, which will allow you to change the responses available to a question.  Using that changes the form for all those viewing/responding at that time.  So you could not concurrently have different responses.  You can have multiple Forms submit to the same file, and then merge the responses if you wished. Or even record them into different files and merge the contents into a common file.

The only other solution would be to create code and deploy the form as a web app.  From that you could have the web app read a spreadsheet file or a sheet and create the responses based on that.  You may want to start [here: Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) and then look at [HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) as a starting point.

Once you have specific questions, create a new post and be sure to include your code.

Comment: So sounds like the best answer is a web form powered off of a spreadsheet.  Thanks for the input. It seemed all I was getting was out of date info about UI apps.